# Proving true or false based on discrete math

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Discrete math practice problems

prove whether true or false

If $a^2$ divides $b^2$, then $a^3$ divides $b^4$

I think it is false because it is true that if $a^2$ divides $b^2$ then $a$ divides $b$ ,

and also true that if $a^2$ divides $b^2$ then $a^4$ divides $b^4$.

could anyone check this one? whether i am right or wrong

much appreciate it

thank you

Comment: You are on the right track. If $a^2$ divides $b^2$ then $a$ divides $b$. From there, observe that $a^n$ divides $b^n$ for all $n$. Then, you can see that $a^k$ divides $b^n$ for $k \leq n$.

Comment: so am i correct that it is false If a^2 divides b^2, then a^3 divides b^4.

Comment: No, the statement is true and you can show it by the steps I wrote above.

Comment: but what if a^2 divides b^3 then a^3 divides b^4? wouldnt it be false?

Comment: Are you now asking if $a^2$ dividing $b^3$ implies $a^3$ divides $b^4$? I would suggest trying some examples with small numbers and convincing yourself why the initial statements made above are true. That understanding will help you with further similar questions.

Comment: yes i am cause i am confused

Comment: If $a$ divides $b$ then for any integer $x$, 1) $ax$ divides $bx$ and 2) $a$ divides $bx$. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: It is true because if a=2 and b=3, then 4 divides 64 then 8 divides 256. hence it is true.

Comment: or am i misunderstanding?

Comment: Please see my first comment.

Comment: If you believe it is false, then you should try to find a counter example.

Answer (score 1):

if a divides b then $a^3$ divides $b^3$

if $a^3$ divides $b^3$ then $a^3$ divides $b * b^3$ so $a^3$ divides $b^4$